# Let $f$ be integrable such that $f(-x,-y)=-f(x,y)$. Show that $\int\int_R f(x,y)$dA=0

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $r>0$ set $R=\{(x,y):-r\leq x,y \leq r\}$ Let $f$ be integrable such that $f(-x,-y)=-f(x,y)$. Show that $\int\int_R f(x,y)$dA=0

I've done this $\int_{-r}^r\int_{-r}^r f(x,y)dxdy$

$=\int_{-r}^r F(x,y)-F(x,-r)dx$

$=F(r,r)-F(-r,r)-F(r,-r)+F(-r,-r)$

$F(r,r)-F(r,r)+F(-r,r)-F(-r,r)=0$

I think this is what I'm supposed to do but I'm not sure what the justifcation is that since $f(-x,-y)=-f(x,y)$ this would also apply to the 2nd integral of that function? So that $F(-x,-y)=-F(x,y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I=\int{\int_{R}{f(x,y)dxdy}}$, and take the change of variables $x=-z$, $y=-w$, then $$I=\int{\int_{R}{f(-z,-w)dzdw}}=-\int{\int_{R}{f(z,w)dzdw}}=-I$$

So we have, $2I=0$,i.e., $I=0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Try the substitution $s=-x, t=-y$.

Comment: $\int_r^{-r}\int_r^{-r}f(s,t)dsdt$?

Comment: @AColoredReptile $\int_r^{-r}\int_r^{-r}f(-s,-t)dsdt$ Now use the given relation for $f$ and change the endpoints of integration.

Comment: $-\int_{-r}^r\int_{-r}^r f(s,t)dsdt$ but I don't see why $\int\int f(s,t)dsdt+\int\int f(-s,-t)dsdt=2I$

Comment: @AColoredReptile Well if you do your sub you get $$\int_{-r}^r\int_{-r}^r f(x,x)dxdx=\int_{-r}^r\int_{-r}^rf(-s,-t)dsdt=-\int_{-r}^r\int_{-r}^r f(s,t)dsdt$$ or in other words $I=-I$.